# How to send data from the Parent to the Child in the AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-bindings

How can I send the data from the **Parent Controller** (index) to the **Child Controller** (Component). Please see the example, instead of the hardcoding the `url` I want to send the parameters for the `Title` and the `URL` from the page controller to the component. I'm stuck to send it and I don't know where is the problem.

**index.html**

```
<div>
  <my-list obj="vm.obj"></my-list>
</div>
```

**index.controller.js**

```
this.obj = {
    testURL: "AngularJS",
    testName: "Testing Environment
}
```

**mylistComponent.html**

```
<span>{{vm.myTestName}}</span>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{{vm.myTestURL}}">AngularJS Wikipedia</a>
```

**mylist.Component.js**

```
binding: {
    obj: "="
}

this.goToPage = function() {
    this.myTestName = this.obj.testName;
    this.myTestURL = this.obj.testURL;
}
```

**[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/aMe1OdKSg6dD3rPGkrC4?p=preview)**

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31225744/in-angular-js-how-do-i-pass-data-from-a-parent-controller-to-a-child-controller?

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/pass-data-from-parent-controller-to-child-controller

Comment: You can broadcast events with $rootscope.$broadcast and listen to it by  $rootscope.$on , by that way you can pass data from one component to another, there are few other methods too, You can have a shared factories to pass the data.

Comment: @slacker Thanks, but I want to use the `binding` data, instead of the service, etc.

Comment: Why not service for this?

Comment: @sivaram636 You should not use rootscope for this. As this is a parent to child situation you can just emit and broadcast on the scope.

Comment: @Milban Have you tried to use `$parent` to access to the parent scope ?

Comment: Somehow I am forced to use the data binding method, therefore I didn't test other way.

Comment: Could you try to create a Plunker to make it easier for us to help you ?

Comment: @MarcusH yeah agree we don't need to use $rootscope here , scope is enough to achieve it

Comment: I've just added the plunker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plunker, by doing this :

```
<test-component value="vm.obj"> </test-component>
```

You put the value of `obj` in the var `value`. So in the child scope you can access to this value with the var `value` not anymore with `obj`.

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/moyIiNLjVCiOAKpKmkPz?p=preview) is your plunker updated.

Comment: Thanks, how can I assign the the value in component controller, because when I assign it, it stops working. ex. `ctrl.testObj = ctrl.value.a`  https://plnkr.co/edit/0kvexzKZKaHZ6PlUGaNk?p=preview

Comment: It's because when you try to assign `ctrl.value.a` to `ctrl.testObj`, `ctrl.value` is still not set in the child scope so `value` is undifined. You can add a **timeout** around your assignation, but there is probably a proper solution

Comment: @Milban Ok, I think a found how to achieve this. You can use $onInit to assign `ctrl.value.a` to `ctrl.testObj`. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/lNGv8GqfuGxH4j5yyjGL?p=preview) is your plunker updated.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time, can you also look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593764/how-to-validate-form-in-angularjs-1-x-component